# Blacklist specific IP on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, web, ip, blacklist

There's a few IP addresses generatings tons of exceptions that can be definitly classified as 'suspicious behaviour'. I want to block just these IPs, but leave everything else alone.

- What is the easiest way to do this with Azure Websites?
- Preferably not with a redeploy.

I found *IP Restrictions* under *Networking*, but it seems that you can just Whitelist, not Blacklist.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways I've done this:

**Using the `<ipSecurity>` tag in web.config**

This isn't Azure-specific, but will work within an Azure Web App. The upside is that you do not have to redeploy. The downside is that touching your web.config will result in your Web App being recycled. This may or may not be a problem for you.

Here's an example:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <ipSecurity>
         <add ipAddress="5.124.39.210" />
      </ipSecurity>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will prevent the turkey at IP address 5.124.39.210 from accessing your site. You can even choose the HTTP response code sent back for restricted IPs (401, 403, 404).

For further details, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/ipSecurity/).

**Roll Your Own**

As mentioned, the bad thing about going the web.config route is that it will require an app restart when your web.config is modified. I've also kept an in-memory cache of restricted IP addresses that were periodically read from a database table. Incoming requests were checked against the blacklist in the Application_BeginRequest method of my HttpApplication subclass.

It goes something along the lines of:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //our own singleton that caches blacklisted IP addresses
       var webSecurity = new CustomWebSecurity();

       var clientIp = Request.UserHostAddress;

       if (webSecurity.IsInBlackList(clientIp))
       {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.StatusCode = 403;
                Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
                Response.End();

                return;
       }
    }
```